# How to advance the y-axis in a loop in matplotlib?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, append

I have a csv file where first column contains the x-axis and all the other columns are various y-axis that I want to plot against x-axis.
I read the the columns by "DictReader" using the "fieldnames".
The different y-axis values I read in a loop using append method, but the problem is that its values never advance to the next column, however legends of these columns are created properly! I tried y_axe.clear() after plt.plot, but did not help. I did not find any examples using append and I suspect that append is the problem here, but I can't figure out how? All the help will be appreciated highly.

```
import csv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


x_axe = []
y_axe = []
with open("file.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for lines in csv_reader:
        x_axe.append(float(lines[csv_reader.fieldnames[0]]))

with open("file.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for i in range(1, len(csv_reader.fieldnames)):
        for lines in csv_reader:
            y_axe.append(float(lines[csv_reader.fieldnames[i]]))
        plt.plot(x_axe, y_axe, label=csv_reader.fieldnames[i])
        # y_axe.clear()   this did not help
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: I think it may help to solve your problem if you use the pandas data frame

Comment: Can you add an example of your input? A few lines of the file would be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

First, you are opening the csv file twice (first to get the `xs`, then the `ys`) which is not necessary nor efficient. Then, in the second part, the reason is not advancing is because you are iterating over the `csv_reader` and once this is depleted, there is nothing more to read, so your iterations are not enough.

You can try putting the `csv_reader` in the outside `for` loop but the problem is that since you are reading row by row, you need to read the entire file before you can plot anything; therefore you can't plot inside the loop and have to use a new `for` to generate the plots. Here's a working example, it's ugly but it works:

```
import csv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import io

dummy_csv_file = '''Y,X1,X2,X3
1,5,10,15
2,6,11,16
3,7,12,17
4,8,13,18
5,9,14,19'''

x_axe = []
y_axe = []
with io.StringIO(dummy_csv_file) as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for lines in csv_reader:
        x_axe.append(float(lines[csv_reader.fieldnames[0]]))


y_axe = []
with io.StringIO(dummy_csv_file) as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)


    for lines in csv_reader:

        for i in range(1, len(csv_reader.fieldnames)):
            y_axe.append(float(lines[csv_reader.fieldnames[i]]))

    # y_axe here contains all the points but are not ordered, a list comprehension will split them into the needed values of each column so we can plot each one
    for y in [y_axe[x::len(csv_reader.fieldnames)-1] for x in range(len(csv_reader.fieldnames)-1)]:
        plt.plot(x_axe, y, label=csv_reader.fieldnames[i])
        # y_axe.clear()   this did not help
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Which outputs:

[image]

However, as someone suggested in the comments, use `pandas` and save all the hustle:

```
import pandas as pd 
import io

dummy_csv_file = '''Y,X1,X2,X3
1,5,10,15
2,6,11,16
3,7,12,17
4,8,13,18
5,9,14,19'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(dummy_csv_file))
df.plot(x="Y", y=["X1", "X2", "X3"])
```

Just a couple of lines of code and same output as above:

[image]

*Note that there is actually a small difference, the label in the x axis. But that's all.